# Can't close Simplemodal from outside function

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, simplemodal

So I create a simplemodal box with an iframe inside of it. in the iframe I have a text box which calls a function once it is submitted. This function then goes off and executes its own commands. What I want to do is after the person submits their text for the simplemodal box to close. I haven't really seen a attribute that allows me to set an id for the modal so I can refer to it outside the function. Here is my code:

the modal:

```
$.modal('<iframe src="chrome-extension://kdcfmjjkjcgaklpmpnhcmieepkiddfen/options.min.html" height="120" width="300" style="border:0">', {
                close: true,
                closeHTML:"",
                containerCss:{
                    backgroundColor:"#000",
                    borderColor:"#000",
                    height:100,
                    padding:0,
                    width:300,
                    height:125
                },
                overlayClose:true,
                opacity:50,
                overlayCss: {backgroundColor:"#000"}
            });
```

the options.min.html:

the passMessage:

```
function passMessage() {
        var value = document.getElementById('speechInput').value;
        var event = "commands"
        $.modal.close();
        chrome.extension.sendRequest({command:value}, function(response) {});
    }
```

as you can see the modal uses the options.min.html to create a speech input box inside the modal. Once the user stops talking another function is called in which the value is taken from that box. However the $.modal.close(); function does not actually close the modal but instead just hangs my program and it goes nowhere. I need to know how to refer to the modal that is created elsewhere.

thanks for any help

Comment: Since $.modal.close(); does seem to work (I ran it from the Chrome console) on the iframe example on http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/, it seems like it should be working for you. No error or warning in your console when you say it hangs your program? Have you set a breakpoint there? Is it just the lack of a semicolon after the previous line (var event = "commands")?

Comment: Well I put alerts before and after the $.modal.close() command and only the before command executes. It hangs on the $.modal.close() command and just stops nothing beyond it gets executed. The var event = "commands" line is actually commented out in my code now so it has no effect at all. The modal stays open and the sendRequest is never sent. If I remove the $.modal.close() line the sendRequest goes through.

Comment: Try replacing $.modal.close() with console.log($.modal) and see what gets logged. Can you post the page, or just the relevant parts, on jsfiddle or jsbin?

Comment: Also, in your original question, the "options.min.html" is missing... not sure if that'll have anything that'll give us a clue, but I'd post it just in case.

Comment: oh wow I don't know why that didn't actually print options.min.html looks like this: `<input id="speechInput" type="text" style="font-size:25px;" x-webkit-speech onwebkitspeechchange="passMessage()" />` it shouldn't have much to do with anything but its there just in case. I don't exactly know where the console.log outputs too. Never actually used it. can you explain that a little more?

Comment: In Chrome, View --> Developer --> JavaScript Console or Developer Tools. There's a console tab on the top, or there'a a button on the bottom that can open the console underneath the other views. Firefox also has it under Tools-->Error Console or Web Console. It also gets pulled into a Firebug tab if you have Firebug installed. IE7+ has it somewhere in the menus too, but I don't have a Windows VM open right now to check. If you're doing any amount of front-end or AJAX dev in your daily job you should get familiar with Firebug & the webkit dev tools ASAP; they're invaluable.

Comment: Are you able to post this page publicly, or copy the relevant parts of your page into a jsfiddle or jsbin?

Comment: well all relevant code is posted here is there a specific reason you want it on those sites?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/obimo6 

that should be all of the relevant code via the site. obviously all code is property of me. I don't exactly know if the full functionality  (the simplemodal in particular) is working because I didn't include the code if that is necessary I will add it

Comment: it seems that when all the code is combined into one file (as in the jsbin) the function works however using the same code in my extension the function hangs on the execution of the $.modal.close(); I did not change anything from my code except removing the iframe. I checked that the iframe and moving between options.min.html and shortcut.js did not cause any issues which it didn't. so it could be the fact that the actual simplemodal code isn't above it even though it is embedded into the page using a content script. So I am at a loss for what the actual problem or discrepancy could be

Comment: Hm, I hadn't noticed that this was all in the context of a chrome extension. Anyway, I asked you to post the code somewhere because there's often no substitute for being able to actually see a problem to help diagnose it. Can't see much of anything going on with the jsbin you posted -- it reports errors, and doesn't generate a modal, so there's no way to test dismissing one.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/obimo6/15/edit this is a newer version I think. it should allow you to create the modal

Comment: the modal works though in this case which makes me confused. However it does still hang. but that could just be because I am doing trying to send a signal to an extension that in this instance doesn't exist. I really appreciate all your help by the way I always seem to run into some issue whenever I try and update this extension.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/obimo6/32/edit

Comment: Sorry, that still isn't functional for me. Anyway, now that I understand you're working on a Chrome extension, I think testing on jsbin may be pointless anyway, since you're working in a very specific environment. Without the source code to the extension to look at, I'd probably suggest you start getting really familiar with this if you haven't already: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tut_debugging.html It explains how to use Chrome's Web Inspector to debug your extension including console logging and the ability to set breakpoints in your scripts.

Comment: well could you tell me how to trigger a click on a link? I have a close button that should close the dialog when clicked. Could I trigger that click or would I need a hardware click?

Comment: Yeah, since you're using SimpleModal, you've already included jQuery, so triggering a click on a link is as simple as $(selector).click(); -- But I'm suspicious that SimpleModal simply binds the same $.modal.close() method to that close button, so you might experience the same hang.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to close the modal from within the iframe, use the following JavaScript:

```
parent.$.modal.close();
```

As for ID's, SimpleModal automatically adds them to the dialog elements: `simplemodal-overlay`, `simplemodal-container`, and `simplemodal-data`

Comment: yeah none of that worked. It still stalls at the close part. I am trying to close the modal from an external function. It goes from shortcuts.js to options.min.html back to shortcuts.js where I want it to then exit the modal and continue on with the commands. However it stalls when it returns to shortcuts.js this is where I am confused. I have tried triggering clicks, referencing the modal in different ways, and a whole bunch of other random things trying to get it to close but it never does.